# jquery menu-show onclick in left side

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to make vk.com style right top menu with jquery.when we click on settings symbol it shows few links whose codes are given below. i am trying with jquery so i tried with slideup and slidedown but i want exactly like vk.com where it displays in left side after click and hides after mouse removed

```
<tr>
  <td class="top_home_link_td">
    <div id="top_logo_down" class=""></div>
    <a onmouseup="removeClass('top_logo_down','tld_d');" onclick="return nav.go(this, event);" onmousedown="addClass('top_logo_down','tld_d');" href="/feed" class="top_home_link"></a>
  </td>
  <td class="top_back_link_td"></td>
  <td style=""><nobr>
    <a onmouseover="gSearch.preload();" onclick="return nav.go(this, event, {search: true, noframe: true});" onmousedown="event.cancelBubble = true;" ontouchstart="event.cancelBubble = true;" href="/search" id="top_search" class="top_nav_link">search</a>
  </nobr></td>
  <td style="" id="support_link_td"><nobr>
    <a onclick="return nav.go(this, event);" onmousedown="event.cancelBubble = true;" ontouchstart="event.cancelBubble = true;" href="/support?act=new" id="top_support_link" class="top_nav_link">help</a>
  </nobr></td>
  <td style="" id="invite_link_td"><nobr>
    <a onclick="return nav.go(this, event);" onmousedown="event.cancelBubble = true;" ontouchstart="event.cancelBubble = true;" href="/invite" id="top_invite_link" class="top_nav_link">invite</a>
  </nobr></td>
  <td id="logout_link_td"><nobr>
    <a onclick="if (checkEvent(event) === false) { location.href = this.href; return cancelEvent(event); }" onmousedown="event.cancelBubble = true;" ontouchstart="event.cancelBubble = true;" href="https://login.vk.com/?act=logout&amp;hash=906cc70a366d6dd462&amp;from_host=vk.com&amp;from_protocol=http" id="logout_link" class="top_nav_link">log out</a>
  </nobr></td>
  <td><nobr>
    <a onmousedown="event.cancelBubble = true; TopSearch.toggleSettings()" ontouchstart="event.cancelBubble = true;" onmouseout="TopSearch.settingsOut()" onmouseover="TopSearch.settingsOver()" class="ts_settings active" id="ts_settings" style="opacity: 1;"></a>
  </nobr></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out .on('[click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)',function(){}); and .on('[mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)',function(){}); jQuery functions.